# How to let Postgres accept remote connections

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to set up a Postgres server and I need it to be able to accept remote connections.

When I make a remote connection from a client, I keep on having this error:

```
Connection to 192.168.1.6:5432 refused.
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
```

I have already edited the file `pg_hba.conf` with these line:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

and

```
host all all ::/0 md5
```

in order to accept every remote connection.
I have also edited the file `postgresql.conf` setting the listen address to `*`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The Error msg instructs to `Check that the hostname and port are correct`. Did you? Is your Postgres instance using port 5432? (`SHOW port;`) And is the client in the same network?  (`192.168.1.6` is a LAN address, not visible from the internet, I assume you are aware of that?) And did you reload after the changes to `postgresql.conf`? If the problem remains, post the complete `pg_hba.conf` file (without the quoted part).

Answer (score 0):

ssh to your server and issue command `netstat -tlpn | grep 5432`
You should get the similar output

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31309/postmaster
tcp        0      0 :::5432                     :::*                        LISTEN      31309/postmaster`

That means postgres is ready to accept remote connections on port 5432. Otherwise you need to recheck listen parameter in postgresql.conf and restart postgresql cluster (not reload). 
If you still can't get remote access, try to temporarily disable firewall on server and client `iptables -F`